# a fast way to generate true-false matrix based on random sampling with a matrix of probability values

Tags: r, random

I have a n × n matrix in which values are between [0,1] and each column has the same values.

These values represent probabilities for each element of the matrix to take the value TRUE or FALSE.

I am searching for a fast way to transform the matrix with the probabilities to a matrix with TRUE/FALSE values based on an independent random sample for each element.

Currently, this code generates what I want (the tf_matrix):

```
n <- 10
p_true <- runif(n,0,1)

p_matrix <- matrix(p_true,n,n, byrow=T)
tf_matrix <- matrix(F, n,n)

for(i in 1:nrow(tf_matrix)) {
    
    for(j in 1:ncol(tf_matrix)) {
        
        tf_matrix[i,j] <- sample(c(T,F), size = 1, prob = c(p_matrix[i,j], 1-p_matrix[i,j]))
        
    }
}
```

However, this is likely very slow, as it uses two for-loops and I need to do this over and over for a large matrix.

Is there a way to make this more efficient (i.e., as fast as possible)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sample(c(T, F), size = 1, prob = x)` is equivalent to `runif(1) < x`. But with `runif` and `<` we can scale up trivially as `<` is vectorized:

```
set.seed(42) ## set seed for reproducibility
n <- 5       ## smaller example is easier to see
p_true <- runif(n,0,1)
p_matrix <- matrix(p_true,n,n, byrow=T)
p_matrix
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
# [1,] 0.914806 0.9370754 0.2861395 0.8304476 0.6417455
# [2,] 0.914806 0.9370754 0.2861395 0.8304476 0.6417455
# [3,] 0.914806 0.9370754 0.2861395 0.8304476 0.6417455
# [4,] 0.914806 0.9370754 0.2861395 0.8304476 0.6417455
# [5,] 0.914806 0.9370754 0.2861395 0.8304476 0.6417455

tf_matrix = runif(n * n) < p_matrix
tf_matrix
#      [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
# [1,] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [2,] TRUE TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# [3,] TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [4,] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [5,] TRUE TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: amazing, thank you very much!